# ASP.NET MVC Futures RequireSSL Attribute and Authorize Attribute Together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Is anyone successfully using both the Authorize and RequireSSL (from MVC futures) attributes together on a controller?  I have created a controller for which I must enforce the rule that the user must be logged in and using a secure connection in order to execute.  If the user is not on a secure connection, I want the app to redirect to https, thus I am using Redirect=true on the RequireSSL attribute.  The code looks something like (CheckPasswordExpired is my homegrown attribute):

```
[Authorize]
[RequireSsl(Redirect = true)]
[CheckPasswordExpired(ActionName = "ChangePassword",
    ControllerName = "Account")]
[HandleError]
public class ActionsController : Controller
{
    ....
}
```

mysite.com/Actions/Index is the default route for the site and also the default page to redirect to for forms authentication.

When I browse to http://mysite.com, what I want to get is the user redirected to a secure connection, and because they are not authenticated yet, to the login page.  What I get is an HTTP 400 error (Bad Request).  If I navigate to http://mysite.com/Account/Login, the redirect works, but neither my Account controller nor Login action method have the [Authorize] attribute.

Anyone have any experience with using these two attributes together to achieve my objective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using both of them with success. Do you have the attributes on your default action?

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
  [Authorize]
  [RequireSsl]
  public ActionResult Index ()
  {
  }
}
```

BTW I'm using a slightly modified version than the futures so that I can disable SSL globally:

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequireSslAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public RequireSslAttribute ()
    {
        Redirect = true;
    }

    public bool Redirect { get; set; }

    public void OnAuthorization (AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Validate.IsNotNull (filterContext, "filterContext");

        if (!Enable)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            // request is not SSL-protected, so throw or redirect
            if (Redirect)
            {
                // form new URL
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                    // use the RawUrl since it works with URL Rewriting
                    Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
                };
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult (builder.ToString ());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException ((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Access forbidden. The requested resource requires an SSL connection.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool Enable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have the attributes attached at the controller level, not at the action level.  BTW, I like your Enable enhancement.

Comment: How do you use Enable though? say in my dev environment I don't want it to be SSL?

Comment: What does Validate.IsNotNull(...) do?  I pasted the code, but don't have Validate (I don't want to install futures hehe)

Comment: Validate is borrowed from https://kigg.svn.codeplex.com/svn/v2.x/Core/Helper/CheckArgument.cs

Comment: For Enable I set it to true/false based on the web.config during application startup.