# Run login page of a ASP.net MVC Azure cloud application on different port than other pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to run login page of ASP.net MVC Azure cloud application on different port than other pages in the same application ?

For example-->
Login page - on port 443
Other web pages - on port 80

Thanks,
Kushal
...

Answer (score 2):

*It is possible.Check out this link and revert back in case of any issue(s)* ***[ASP.NET MVC Futures RequireSSL Attribute and Authorize Attribute Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133079/asp-net-mvc-futures-requiressl-attribute-and-authorize-attribute-together)***

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.http://sol3.net/blogs/aspinsiders/archive/2009/04/06/the-mvc-framework-the-requiresslattribute.aspx